# Convert text links to <a> tag

Tags: php, regex

On my website users have an ability to create articles, using simple text editor.
Usually in that articles i see links like this: *http://example.com* as a plain text. I need a simple PHP-function to convert such links to this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

First i was thinking about simple regex replace, but what if user saves article the second time? This code will be regex'ed once more:

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="<a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>"><a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a></a>
```

Any suggestions, how to solve this problem?

EDITED:
I used lots of regexes, the last one was:

`/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\/\S*)+?/`

Comment: I think your taking the problem (converting text to html) from the wrong end: your link conversion should happen during publication phase not during editing phase like now. Beside it should be bi-directional (convert and back-convert). Since this start to be a more complex problem you want to turn to already existing frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

$pattern = '/(^http.+com$)/i';
Is your pattern something like the above?